# Android Emulator Control buttons not shown

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

I have Android Studio 2.1.1 and because I didn't had any free space left on C, I moved my Android sdk folder on another drive and I also mounted a new device. Everything works well except that I no longer have the emulator buttons from where I can control my device(power off, volume up, down, orientation etc). I'm talking about the red circle in the picture and I am most interested in the menu you get if you click the "..." in the blue circle (call the device, send sms, change gps etc).
Do you know how is that menu called and how I can open it?
[image]

Comment: If you press F1, are you getting the usual options?  You should also see a list of keyboard shortcuts under Help. Can't explicitly see an option to hide that menu though, so are your Android emulator tools up to date?

Comment: If I press F1 nothing happens. I mention that I am using Windows. Well I didn't changed anything. Yestarday it worked and all I did was to move the android-sdk folder from C to E.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is removing and re-installing the emulator via SDK Manager. Do you get the same issue with a freshly-created virtual device?

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue with all the virtual devices, altough I already had some of them and they had the menu.